# Generic XSLT transformation code

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I've got quite some challenge in here...

Is it possible to have an XSL code that will apply to whatever hierarchy of XML, to transform it into nested HTML list?

**Example XML:**

```
<Base>
  <Parent>
    <Child />
    <Child>
      <ChildOne />
      <ChildOne>
       <ChildTwo />
       <ChildTwo />
      </ChildOne>
    </Child>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <Child>
      <ChildOne>
        <ChildTwo>
          <ChildThree>
            <ChildFour />
          </ChildThree>
          <ChildThree/>
        </ChildTwo>
      </ChildOne>
      <ChildOne/>
      <ChildOne/>
    </Child>
    <Child/>
  </Parent>
</Base>
```

**Desired result:**

```
<ul>
  <li>Parent1
    <ul>
      <li>Child</li>
      <li>Child
        <ul>
        <li>ChildOne</li>
        <li>ChildOne>
           <ul>
              <li>ChildTwo</li>
              <li>ChildTwo</li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Parent2
    <ul>
      <li>Child
        <ul>
            <li>ChildOne
                <ul>
                    <li>ChildTwo
                  <ul>
                  <li>ChildThree
                     <ul>
                         <li>ChildFour</li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>ChildThree</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li>ChildOne</li>
            <li>ChildOne</li>
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Child</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So the logic is that if there is other elements(suppressed el.) under an element(upper el.) - the suppressed el. get surround by `<li>name of upper el.<ul>all suppressed el.</ul></li>` and so on.

My point is that this XSL code works not by values or names of elements or attributes, but by condition checking, if there are other elements falling under a particular element.

F.e., if `ChildThree` didn't have `ChildFour` under itself, it would just be `<li>ChildThree>` instead of

```
<li>ChildThree
   <ul>
      <li>ChildFour</li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Hope I explained myself clear. :)

P.S. This is how it has to look in the browser, more or less (just to give visual representation, as we humans like to see the things. :P )

[image]

Comment: Your input XML has three `Child` elements under the first `Parent` whereas the desired output XML only has two `li` elements with "Child" text. Is that correct and if so, what is the logic? (And the same question for the `ChildOne` elements.)

Comment: @Ben - sorry, my mistake. I corrected it now. The input and output have to have the same number of elements (as they do now). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*[*]">
  <li>
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
  </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
  <li>
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
  </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*" priority="5">
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ul>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Saxon 6.5.5 transforms the input

```
<Base>
  <Parent>
    <Child />
    <Child>
      <ChildOne />
      <ChildOne>
       <ChildTwo />
       <ChildTwo />
      </ChildOne>
    </Child>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <Child>
      <ChildOne>
        <ChildTwo>
          <ChildThree>
            <ChildFour />
          </ChildThree>
          <ChildThree/>
        </ChildTwo>
      </ChildOne>
      <ChildOne/>
      <ChildOne/>
    </Child>
    <Child/>
  </Parent>
</Base>
```

into the result

```
<ul>

   <li>Parent
      <ul>

         <li>Child</li>

         <li>Child
            <ul>

               <li>ChildOne</li>

               <li>ChildOne
                  <ul>

                     <li>ChildTwo</li>

                     <li>ChildTwo</li>

                  </ul>
               </li>

            </ul>
         </li>

      </ul>
   </li>

   <li>Parent
      <ul>

         <li>Child
            <ul>

               <li>ChildOne
                  <ul>

                     <li>ChildTwo
                        <ul>

                           <li>ChildThree
                              <ul>

                                 <li>ChildFour</li>

                              </ul>
                           </li>

                           <li>ChildThree</li>

                        </ul>
                     </li>

                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li>ChildOne</li>

               <li>ChildOne</li>

            </ul>
         </li>

         <li>Child</li>

      </ul>
   </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This XSL stylesheet gives you want you're after.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!-- Match the Base element, with high priority to avoid matching the more
       specific template further down, that matches *[*] -->
  <xsl:template match="Base" priority="10">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match the Parent element, with high priority to avoid matching the more
       specific template further down, that matches *[*] -->
  <xsl:template match="Parent" priority="10">
    <li>
      <!-- Output a Parent element and append it with its position amongst
           all Parent elements at this level. -->
      <xsl:text>Parent</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::Parent) + 1"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match those elements that have children. -->
  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match the remaining elements (without children) -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can see it in action [here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/A3K3Fo).